# How to use store in an initializer

Tags: ember.js

I want to use the store in an initializer to I tried to do this :

```
export function initialize(application) {
  application.inject('controller', 'store', 'service:store');
  this.store.createRecord('model');
}

export default {
  name: 'modify-models',
  initialize
};
```

With this, `this.store` is undefined.

As in [the doc](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_initializer-arity), I tried `var store = application.lookup('service:store');` but `application.lookup` is undefined.

I also tried `var store = Ember.inject.service('store');` but `store` is undefined.

I can't find the right way. What's the solution?

Comment: I would not create Ember Data objects in an initializer. Initializers are designed for "true" initialization such as injections. Just create the object in the `beforeModel` hook of your application route, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure it is an [instance initializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/applications/initializers/#toc_application-instance-initializers), and you need to make it run after `ember-data`:

```
export default {
  name: 'modify-models',
  after: 'ember-data',
  initialize
};
```

Comment: My initializer was not an instance initializer. I changed and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if there is a solution to use the store in an application initializer or to reopen a class in a instance initializer?

Comment: @Dougui if you use `after: 'ember-data'` you should be able to get the store in the application initializer, did you try that? Not sure about reopening a class, though.

Comment: Yes I did. I have to do more search to understand what's happening

Comment: I suggest visiting our [Slack](https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com/) group and asking there :)